# jQuery button don't change its class instantly because of AJAX call

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

When my button is clicked,I want to change it's class instantly,but it seems that the ajax call is not letting it to happen.It's happening 3-4 seconds later.Why?I tested with alerts and it's ok.

the button:

```
    $('#myButton').click(function() {
        alert("ok");//it will alert instantly
        $('#myButton').removeClass().addClass("btn btn-success"); //here, this code is running after 3-4 secs
    });
```

ajax call:

```
 $('button').click(function() {
     ...some code...
     $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: myUrl,
            data: myValue,
            success: function(data) {
                setTimeout(function() { 
                    img.src = img.src;
                }, 10);
            }

        })

}
```

Without the ajax call it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this:

```
async: false
```

Adding that makes the asynchronous operation artificially synchronous, blocking everything else from happening in the browser.  You're probably even getting a warning about deprecation in your browser's development console.

Never use `async: false`.  Keep asynchronous operations asynchronous.

Comment: David but without  async: false is it possible to have   img.src = img.src; in success?

Comment: @ThiTle: Of course, why wouldn't it?  When you test it, does it fail in some way?